# Using SQL in Python to compare fields and update columns accordingly

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I have 2 tables:

1.source_table

2.target_table

I want to check if x,y,z, fields from source table have any match to A,B,C fields in target_table,

```
          IF yes:

                 Update values P,Q,R,S in target_table from H,I,J,K fields in source table
          Else 
                 insert a new row with fields X,Y,Z. H,I,J,K fields  from source table to A,B,C,P,Q,R,S in target_table
```

I am new to using SQL statements in python and I have attempted it as,

```
             sql = 'select H, I, J, K from %s where X=? and Y=? and Z=?' \
                % source_table
             row = cursor.execute(sql, values).fetchone()

             sql = 'select A, B, C from %s where A=? and B=? and C=?' \
                % target_table

             tocompare_row = cursor.execute(sql, values).fetchone()

             if X == tocompare_row[0] and Y == tocompare_row[1] and Z== tocompare_row[2]:
                 sql = 'Update %s SET P=%s, Q=%s, R=%s, S=%s where A=? and B=? and C=? ' \
                   % target_table, row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3]

                 cursor.execute(sql, [X, Y, Z])

              else :
                sql = 'Insert into  %s (A, B, C, P, Q, R, S) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)' \
                  % target_table, X, Y, Z, row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3]
                cursor.execute(sql)
```

Can someone please tell me if I am doing it right?

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Did you try to run this? If yes, what was the result?

Comment: Hi @user3885927 : I did not get an out put , I did not get an error, but there was no output either. So I thought I was making an error. Is it logically correct ?

Comment: what is X in your X == tocompare_row[0]?

Comment: hi @user3885927 This code is inside a function, so X, Y ,Z are the arguments that I pass to this function

Comment: I don't think this will do what you want. It seems to me you are grabbing first row from each table and comparing. You should match each row in source table with each row in the target table. Honestly something like this is better to do inside a stored procedure. Is there a reason why you can't do that?

Comment: @user3885927: I am grabbing the first row that meets the WHERE clause as I want only one row that meets all conditions of the WHERE clause

Comment: OK, seems you are just using specific inputs (X,Y,Z) and checking in both tables. (1) You can just see row count of target >0 and do update else insert (2) I don't see a commit statement. Do you have it set in your connection string? If not that may be your issue. Unless you commit, insert and updates won't happen.